# What is the default target for an annotation when annotating property in Kotlin?

Tags: annotations, jackson, kotlin, jongo

Annotations in Kotlin can have different use-site targets as explained here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

My question is: When use-site is not explicitly defined, what is the default target when annotating property in a class like in the example below?

```
class Test {
  @SomeAnnotation
  var someProperty: String? = null
}
```

**Background**

I'm trying Jongo as MongoDB client in Kotlin and have problems annotating id field. Jongo does not map id property correctly when it's annotated like this:

```
@MongoId @MongoObjectId var id: String? = null
```

The annotations in question are just meta-annotations for Jackson. However it seems to work when I annotate the property like this, indicating use-site problem:

```
@field:[MongoId MongoObjectId]
var id: String? = null
```

I would expect that `@field` is default use-site, but it seems that it isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) says:

> If you don’t specify a use-site target, the target is chosen according
>   to the `@Target` annotation of the annotation being used. If there are
>   multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target from the
>   following list is used:
>
> - `param` (constructor parameter)
> - `property` (annotations with this target are not visible to Java)
> - `field`

So if your annotation has `@Target({ElementType.FIELD})`, the annotation in Kotlin will target `@field:`.

If it has no `@Target` specified, it may be used on any program element: the `@property:` target is also applicable and is chosen by default.

Comment: Ah.. I somehow missed that part even though I was actively looking for it. This explains why mapping doesn't work without specifying @field. MongoId doesn't have TARGET, and property annotations are not visible to Java. Since Jongo uses Jackson which expects annotation on field or getter, it cannot see the annotation.

Comment: @KresimirNesek you want it on the getter for Jackson, so `@get:SomeAnnotation` for the property.