# Kotlin support for @ColorInt Java Annotation

Tags: android, annotations, kotlin, lint

Does Kotlin support java annotations like `@ColorInt`, because i cannot get it to work. I can annotate a color with `@ColorInt`, but don't actually get the lint checks for that annotation.

Example

```
    fun setStatusBarColor(@ColorInt color){
        window.setStatusBarColor(color)
    }
```

When passing `R.color.colorPrimary`, no lint is shown. Should show lint with `R.color.colorPrimary` and don't show with `resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)`

Comment: I would assume so ( https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html ) but maybe kotlin for Android is a bit different; or: lint simply doesn't know about that.

Comment: The lint check you mentioned might haven't been implemented yet for Kotlin: only subset of those has been ported, though all are planned.

Comment: Also, can you share code of where you used the annotation?  If on a property, what annotation target did you set?  (for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361162/what-is-the-default-target-for-an-annotation-when-annotating-property-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Kotlin language definitely supports all Java annotations. The Lint checks you're talking about are not part of either the Java language or the Kotlin language, but rather a feature of Android Studio and the Android plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. That feature is currently supported only for Java, and we plan to support it for Kotlin in a future update of the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It is the lint check that i miss the most, because its easy to write R.color.xxx instead of resolved color res

Comment: Three years later and it still doesn't work. Came here after wasting two hours trying to figure out why my `setBackgroundColor(R.color.white)` looked blue.

Comment: @yole can you point direction where can I contribute and maybe write that :) ? We use that in our project, and to keep things clean and for Kotlin advantage I would really like to support that.

Comment: @yole bright future they say https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11392

Comment: For our app, the colors are the adjustable on a PC and sent to the app. It's ridiculous that such a simple feature is impossible in Kotlin. Colors setting during compile time is not done.