# dagger 2, what is difference between @set:Inject and @Inject

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

In a android, kotlin project,  seeing this `@set:Inject`  but could not find a good explanation. Anyone knows?

```
object Controller {

    @set:Inject
    lateinit var someData: SomeData
```

Comment: it determines whether the inject annotation is on the field, the getter or the setter.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35362799/2413303

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `@Inject` annotation can be used for method, constructor, or field:

```
@Target(value={METHOD,CONSTRUCTOR,FIELD})
```

It is important to remember that Java code will be generated from this Kotlin code and for one statement in Kotlin you can have multiple Java elements and that is why `@set:Inject` explicitly specifies that the `@Inject` annotation should be applied to the setter that will be generated in Java.

What happens if there is no use-site target defined? [Official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) provides a good explanation:

> If you don't specify a use-site target, the target is chosen according
>   to the @Target annotation of the annotation being used. If there are
>   multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target from the
>   following list is used:
>
> - param (constructor parameter);
> - property (annotations with this target are not visible to Java);
> - field;